# New Dell unable to boot after clone from old laptop

Tags: windows, clone, optane

So I have cloned 100s of various computers over the years and suddenly we are consistently running into issues with new Dell laptops with Intel Optane NVME hard drives. I have tried to clone with multiple cloning programs and get the same error "inaccessible boot device". In the past, we would turn off Raid in the SATA options and disable Secure Boot. That usually fixed things. Then if needed, we would convert the drive to GPT and recreate the boot partitions. Now that does not work on these newer Dells with Optane NVME hard drives. I have recreated the boot EFI and MSR boot partitions, also tried renaming the BCD and then running the bootrec /rebuildbcd command. Also, ran check disk on the drive and it was clean. If I pull the drive and install it on another PC, it boots just fine, so I know the clone and boot partition are good. Anybody else have issues with cloning to the newer Dells with optane drives?

Comment: What cloning software did you use?

Comment: Mainly HD Clone, but tried with Acronis and Clonezilla.

Comment: So I just replaced the 250GB Optane drive with a Western Digital and it cloned over fine with HD Clone. A well spent $40 to get this dealt with. I would still like to know if others have experienced this since this will continue to be an issue going forward. I may try other clone software.